# Using page properties in a semantic mediawiki #ask query

Tags: mediawiki, semantics

What is the best way to construct an *#ask* query using semantic properties from the current page?

Let's say I have a page with the properties 'featurestart (has type::Number)', 'featurestop (has type::Number)' and 'srcfeature (has type::Page)'. Featurestart and featurestop are coordinates. I want to find the next query along the same srcfeature.

```
{{#ask:
[[featurestart::>{{#show: {{PAGENAME}} | ?featurestop}}]]
[[srcfeature::{{#show: {{PAGENAME}} | ?srcfeature}}]]
| limit=1
}}
```

The #ask query fails, giving the error:

> The part "|Scaffold 16" of the query was not understood. Results might
>   not be as expected.

Where 'Scaffold 16' is the value of the srcfeature property on the page I was testing. Note the extra "|" character.

The featurestart (a numeric property) works just fine. I suspect that problem is caused by the *#show* query returning not just the name of the property, but a formatted link.

---

Is there any way to either clean the return value of *#show* so that just the value is given?
***OR***
Is there a better way of retrieving properties for the current page so that they can be included in an #ask query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the *#show* query here is returning a wiki link to the scaffold_16 page, rather than just the text.

The *#ask* query needs clean text, so the *#show* query needs to specify **link=none**:

```
[[srcfeature::{{#show: {{PAGENAME}} | link=none | ?srcfeature}}]]
```